# using ajax to handle file upload

Tags: php, ajax

I have a html form on my website that accepts `application/pdf file type`

```
<input id="userfile" name="userfile" type="file" accept="application/pdf" style="display:none"/>
```

And a js function to handle the file and make an ajax request:

```
$('#userfile').on('input', function() {
    var test_test = $('#userfile')[0].files[0];
    var test_form = new FormData();
    test_form.append('file', test_test);
    console.log($('#userfile')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dinkle_berry_test.php',
        method: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        data: {test_form},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
                }
        });
    })
```

This is what I can confirm in console:
[image]

However, when submitted, php echos back:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\dinkle_berry_test.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
```

My PHP code for dinkle_berry_test.php:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'C:/xampp/htdocs/tmp_upload/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

I can't seem to get the file to upload to this folder. Not sure what is going on. I've ready multiple forms, but can't seem to find a working answer.

Comment: Please share compete form, js and PHP code

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is this:

```
data: {test_form},
```

to test if you are getting any file on server side print the ouput of the File Variable:

```
echo var_dump($_FILES);
```

and take note of your result.

**But:**

i have a diferent script to handle all form element:

```
function ToAjax(form) { //target form
    var jsonObj = [];
    var formData = new FormData();
    //Form element
    $('[name="' + form + '"] *').not(':input[type=file], :input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset], :input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').filter(':input').each(function(obj, v) {
        var iObj = {};
        var input = $(this);
        var inputname = input.attr("name");
        if (typeof inputname !== typeof undefined && inputname !== false) { //handle attribute names
            inputname = inputname.replace(/-/g, '_'); //handle underscore
            var val = input.val();
            var inputval = val;
            iObj[inputname] = inputval;
            jsonObj.push(iObj);
        }
    });
    //Summernote textarea editor
    $('[name="' + form + '"] *').filter('div.sumertextarea').each(function(obj, v) {
        var iObj = {};
        var input = $(this);
        var inputname = input.attr("data-name");
        inputname = inputname.replace(/-/g, '_');
        var val = input.summernote('code');
        var inputval = val;
        iObj[inputname] = inputval;
        jsonObj.push(iObj);
    });
    //compres in json data
    jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    //parse json to formdata
    formData.append('jsonData', jsonData);
    //handle all file types input
    $('[name="' + form + '"] *').filter(':input[type=file]').each(function(obj, v) {
        if (typeof v.files[0] != 'undefined') {
            var file = v.files[0];
            var name = $(v).attr("name");
            name = name.replace(/-/g, '_');
            formData.append(name, file);
        }
    });
    //handle all File type from dropzone plugin
    $('[name="' + form + '"] *').filter('div.dropzone').each(function() {
        var DropFile = $(this)[0].dropzone.getAcceptedFiles();
        for (Nof in DropFile) {
            var file = DropFile[Nof];
            var name = DropFile[Nof].name;
            name = name.replace(/-/g, '_');
            formData.append(name, file);
        }
    });
    //send all data packet to send ajax function.
    window.SendAjax(formData);
}
```

to send to the server side i use this:

```
function SendAjax(formdata) {
    var url = 'index.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: formdata,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert(error);
        },
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            alert(resp);
        }
    });
}
```

and yes i am use `contenType: false` instead of `contentType: 'multipart/form-data',`

becouse i can handle more easy in server side the data, to acces to files you have 2 seccion file sistema or dropzone plugin check the result array diference an take care of adapt or use it in your project:

2 file example send at same time, PDF and JPG this ouput test of $_FILES common form and dropzone plugin:

```
["i_file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "test.pdf"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "test.jpg"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "application/pdf"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(24) "C  :\ xampp\tmp\phpDDC5.tmp"
      [1]=>
      string(24) "C  :\ xampp\tmp\phpDDC6.tmp"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
      [1]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(180572)
      [1]=>
      int(8984)
    }
  }
```

With dropzone plugin:

```
["test_jpg"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "prueba.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(24) "C  :\ xampp\tmp\phpDDC7.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(8984)
  }
  ["test_pdf"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "prueba.pdf"
    ["type"]=>
    string(15) "application/pdf"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(24) "C  :\ xampp\tmp\phpDDC8.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(180572)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was enclosing the `formData()` within curly braces `{}`.

Because formData is already an object, I was sending an object of objects to the php file. I simply removed the {} from the data parameter of the ajax call and everything works just as it should.

This is what worked in php:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'C:/xampp/htdoc/tmp/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Hope this helps someone. Be careful with how you handle datatypes in any project.

Answer (score -1):

The name of your file field is userfile and in php backend you are calling file field hence you are getting the error. Change your backend to

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`

It will work your ajax and all are working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use FormData to handle the data before using it in your ajax request?
Here's a link: [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

Hope this helps